# keep selected value in select control after page refresh in laravel

Tags: laravel

in my blade :

```
<select id="Priority_id" style="width:180px;" class="myform-select">
    <option value="" selected>Select priority</option>
     @foreach ($priorities as $priority)
          <option value="{{ $priority->id }}">
              {{ $priority->Desc }}
          </option>
     @endforeach
</select>
```

to keep old value of select i change to this:

```
<select id="Priority_id" style="width:180px;" class="myform-select">
    <option value="" selected>Select priority</option>
    @foreach ($priorities as $priority)
           <option value="{{ $priority->id }}" {{ ( old('Priority_id')==$priority->id ? "selected":"") }}>
                    {{ $priority->Desc }}
           </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

But when refreshing the page, select does not keep the previous value.

Comment: sounds like you will need to be reflashing the flash data every time

Answer (score 0):

Laravel allows you to keep input from one request during the next request. This feature is particularly useful for re-populating forms after detecting validation errors.

However, when you refresh the page, the controller doesn't know what the previous request was, which is why it won't work here.

Comment: how to solve it?

Comment: You can pass data from controller to the view using `with()`, or maybe you should use sessions.